# How to display the new users in Laravel in real time

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, laravel

I'm making a web app project using Laravel and React. The data is displaying normally, but each time it is updated the page need to be refreshed manually in order to show the new information's in the database.

How can I display for example the last users registered in real time? Without refreshing the page?

I'm currently using MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real time database changes with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548130/real-time-database-changes-with-ajax)

Comment: I think your suggestion maybe a solution, but continuous Ajax requests each second will tax heavily the server, especially if I have 100 users doing those requests simultaneously.

Comment: From your question is not clear what you exactly want to achieve.
Do you need the page to be able to show you when new users register on your web site or you just need the page to add the user to the DB and append him/her on the page?

Comment: I want my page to show the actual new users that were added in the database from another page or directly from the database itself. Without refreshing the page.

Comment: If Ajax is not an option, you need web sockets for that.

Comment: I think so. I have never used Websockets but I will give it a try. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use websockets to listen for a notification and trigger an ajax request to get the data from the server and update the front end

A few different options

https://pusher.com/

https://www.twilio.com/sync

https://socket.io/

https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction

Comment: I will take a look at that, thank you. But if you don't mind me asking, I was thinking about maybe integrating a firebase database along with the existing Mysql one in order to specifically show the new users, what do you think about that ?

Comment: I would probably use websockets to trigger an ajax request rather than a rtdb. Laravel has built in support for pusher, it works well but can get pricey for larger apps https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting I'm using twilio sync in my most recent app and it's good but I had to build a custom broadcaster and channels and notification system. Firebase also has cloud messaging to implement push notifications. I've never used socket.io or the beyondcode package tho

Comment: Yes I managed to implement Websockets and without the usage of Pusher, just the local server. So far everything is working fine. I tested pushing an event with `php artisan tinker` and it worked. Now I want to know how to "link" between my table in the database and the websockets. For now I can show successfully a message in the console using this `<script>Echo.channel('home').listen('NewPatient',(e) => {console.log(e.patient);  })</script> `. **Home** is the name of the channel, **NewPatient** is the name of the event.

Comment: So instead in console, display it somewhere on page? @BronzeJamie

Comment: No, what I mean is, should I put the same code I have to display the Patients normally that I have in `PatientController` in the Event code and then call it ?

Comment: Set up an API route that populates the front end and call it on page load via an AJAX request and then call it again when you receive the notification to repopulate the data. If you haven't decoupled your front end I would set up an API route anyway which calls a method to return JSON, in that method call a getData() method which returns your db data. Your normal method can also call getData but return a view response. Then you can get the same data and just handle the response differently depending on if it's ajax or page load. Also there is a wantsJson helper on the request object